# How to batch install setup-file (*.exe) on PC?

Tags: windows, installation, batch, setup, portable

Instead of repeatedly double-clicking tens of setup files (*.exe), can batch-installing at once be possible? Or at least one double-click is enough to sequentially activate them?

The closest Google solutions would be [Ninite](https://ninite.com/) and [Speed Install](http://speed-install.software.informer.com/). However, both only offer choices of some preset, well-known, programs, not customizable enough to embrace some of my stored (*.exe) files.

Considering the foreseeable repetitive procedure in future, could there be a way to get around it?

Comment: If all executables are in the same folder, the FOR command could be used to start each setup. You still need to guide each setup through its install and click next etc. If you want to make everything go in one click, you'll need more than just FOR. A macro scripting tool that can send key-strokes would then be required, but its likely a lot more time-consuming building that than it is to use afterwards. Only if you need to do lots of installs on 30+ computers, macro-based installing is worth considering.

Comment: @LPChip I'd check whether EXEs allow unattended installation by some command line switch.

Comment: @JosefZ I know, but that means FOR no longer can be used because the unattended install switch is different per setup. Some have /s some /q some /silent, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Common installers do have options for "silent installation". For example, Innosetup's have command line option `/VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /DIR="C:\INSTALL\PATH"` for this purpose, while NSIS installers have `/S /D=C:\Install Path\No Quotes Allowed Even If Space Present`.

See [Unattended Installation](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php) for more information.

Of course, silent installations offer little choices, e.g. you cannot decide whether to install a 32-bit or a 64-bit R package, but to install both.

As an example, below is a batch file I created to automatically install TeXmacs and maxima to the multimedia system in my classroom. The two subroutines in it may be useful.

```
setlocal

set "main_dir=%USERPROFILE%\DESKTOP"
set "TeXMacs_dir=%main_dir%\mathsofts\TeXMacs"
set "maxima_dir=%main_dir%\mathsofts\maxima"

call :silent_install_inno "%~dp0TeXmacs.exe" "%TeXMacs_dir%"
call :silent_install_nsis "%~dp0maxima.exe" "%maxima_dir%"

endlocal
exit /b

:silent_install_inno
:: parameters: %1--path to the installer executable
::             %2--installation path
start "" /wait %1 /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /DIR=%2
exit /b

:silent_install_nsis
:: parameters: %1--path to the installer executable
::             %2--installation path
:: note: NO QUOTES in %2 is allowed, so %~2 should be used to de-quote
start "" /wait %1 /S /D=%~2
exit /b
```